# Concatinating the Three Strings based on their existance

Tags: xslt

I have a requirement to concatenate the 3 string with "," delimiter:

I/P XML:

```
<Data>
<First>XXX</First>
<Second>YYY</Second>
<Third>ZZZ</Third>
</Data>
```

## O/P Expected:

If all elements has data then `<Concatinate>XXX,YYY,ZZZ</Concatinate>`

or If Second element is empty  then  `<Concatinate>XXX,ZZZ</Concatinate>`

or If Third element is empty  then

```
<Concatinate>XXX,YYY</Concatinate>
```

How can i achieve this, Please suggest.

Regards,
Vishnu.

Comment: Please add whatever you have attempted so far. That would help in providing a correct answer.

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: @Michael, yes my processor supports XSLT 2.0 but this solution needs to be implement in the existing XSLT 1.0

Comment: Well, you have answers for both, so you should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:template match="Data">
        <Concatinate>
          <!-- Matching all Child that is not empty -->
        <xsl:for-each select="child::*[normalize-space()]">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
             <!-- below code is use to put comma if position is not last -->
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </Concatinate>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to give some precisions to your code (explain how it works).

Comment: it goes to every child element of Data element and place it value and comma (except last element)

Comment: Ok, but please edit your answer with these informations to repect the answer format required by stackoverflow's guidelines.

Comment: @Uday, Sorry the solution you provided using XSLT 1.0 is not working. It is not giving me the desired output

Answer (score 0):

In **XSLT 2.0**

```
  <xsl:template match="Data">
        <Concatinate><xsl:value-of select="First[node()]|Second[node()]|Third[node()]" separator=","/></Concatinate>
    </xsl:template>
```

also in **XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <Concatinate><xsl:apply-templates/></Concatinate>
    </xsl:template>

     <!-- Template to handle Child Element  -->
    <xsl:template match="First[node()]|Second[node()]|Third[node()]">
        <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::*[node()]"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet
```

Comment: Thanks @Rupesh, it worked in XSLT2.0; but i want to implement this in XSLT1.0, could you please help?

Comment: for XSLT1.0 solution you refer @uday answer